# How to select specific data between Quotes (")

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am reposting my question as I am new to SQL 2012.

I want to fetch the numeric data between quotes (") in the following rows,

row1:'asdalknd,"**1,2,3,4**",slknsdl,"**5,6,7,8**",snlsn'

row2:'asknd,"**111,267,387,4756**",snsdl,"**534,646,767,348**",snlssdsdsdsjkvkn'

row3'....

row4'....

row5'....

row6'...

row7'...

row8'....

The above mentioned are the rows of a single column.

I just want to extract the numerics(may be in another column for each rows)

Can anybody pls help, as this is way above my basic knowledge of t-sql.

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: "Somehow I tried the Substring function" means that you should have at least one attempt to do this yourself. Can you [edit] your question to include it? And add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using at the same time? (It's also unclear whether what you've posted is a single row or three separate rows. If you want us to help you, you need to make it very clear and specific about what you're asking. We can't see your screen or read your mind from where we sit.)

Comment: Sorry.. its a SQL 2012 query

Comment: SOrry Ken, I am kind of new to the blog.

Comment: I don't see any semicolons in the string, so getting the numbers is easy.  They are `NULL`.

Comment: All records are different rows in same column.

Comment: Semicolon = `;`, `,` = comma

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. I want to extract the numbers in the bold.

Comment: It's OK. The first thing you should know then is that this isn't a blog, or a forum, or a discussion group. It's a site for specific questions about programming related problems, with an emphasis on the word **specific**. :-) And @Gordon is correct; there are zero semicolons (`;`) in any of the sample data you provided. None, meaning "not a single one".

Comment: thanks for that Ken.. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @user3617463 - I edited your post to make it more readable.  If you are not satisfied with the result - feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: You may want to look into [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

Comment: By semicolon (`;`) do you mean double quotes (`"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is **Ugly**, but will eventually work:

COLUMN  = `'jksjdksls#$#$@@kskjfjf,"123,456,789" lsnslkdswfnslsjfls'`

`left(
       right(COLUMN,len(COLUMN)-instr(COLUMN,"""")),
       instr(
              right(COLUMN,len(COLUMN)-instr(COLUMN,"""")),
              """") -1
      )`

--> `123,456,789`

This is what is done:

- We take this string `'jksjdksls#$#$@@kskjfjf,"123,456,789" lsnslkdswfnslsjfls'`
- find the first occurence of " with `instr(COLUMN,"""")` --> returns 24
- take the right end of the string with. Therefore we need to take the length of the string with `len(COLUMN)`--> 55 and substract the position of the first " (24)
- then we need to find the second " with `instr()`in the right string, which we need to create again with `right(COLUMN,len(COLUMN)-instr(COLUMN,""""))` and substract 1 for the ".